# Strange Github Issue - Permission Denied (publickey) even bitbucket has same issue

Tags: git, github

First I tried with explicitly specifying (have a look at following comman), it prompts for the passpharse. So, It is reading the right key file.

```
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Connecting to github.com [204.232.175.90] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/mohit_thakral/.ssh/id_rsa.pub type 1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version PANSSH_0.1
debug1: no match: PANSSH_0.1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/mohit_thakral/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/mohit_thakral/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/mohit_thakral/.ssh/id_rsa.pub':
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Second I tried without the file. Still same issue.

```
$ ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Connecting to github.com [204.232.175.90] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/mohit_thakral/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/mohit_thakral/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/mohit_thakral/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version PANSSH_0.1
debug1: no match: PANSSH_0.1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/mohit_thakral/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/mohit_thakral/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/mohit_thakral/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/mohit_thakral/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I have checked the signature of the key using following command as well.

```
ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: Did you tell the respective services what your public key is?

Comment: Yes, Ok. So, seems like my company's network is not allowing something. Can I figure out what that is

Comment: I know outbound SSH can be blocked by a lot of corporate networks to prevent tunneling outside of the network. Take a look at using HTTPS to clone the repositories instead of SSH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: You don't use your public key to authenticate, but the private key.

It looks like either you don't have the private key or you haven't told GitHub what your *public* key is. `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and then copy and paste that into the SSH keys in your GitHub account panel.

If you're still having trouble, you could also try to contact GitHub Support at support@github.com.

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks for answer. Apologies, I read it somewhere that it uses private key, but forgot while putting this post.

I tried in mobaxterm as well. Generated new key added it to ssh keys of github, and tried ssh -T git@github.com, without the key. It didn't work.